# ASP.NET WebAPI throw 404 if method parameter is string or int

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I did a very simple test on ASP.NET MVC4 WebAPI and found some interesting issue:

When a method is taking complex type, it will work, but when it takes string or int, it will throw 404, as the screen shot given: The "AddProduct" works, but "Test" and "Test1" is always not found.

How should I invoke the method correctly?

[image: Web API Code]

[image: 404 when invoking the Test method]

[image: my route config]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried,

```
$.ajax({
  url : "/api/product/test",
  data : { username : "edi" },
  dataType : "json",
  type : "POST",
  success : function(res){ console.log(res); },
  error : function(req, stat, err){ console.log(stat + ": " + err); }
});
```

Right now it's failing becuase you've wrapped your entire json object (in the jquery ajax method) in quotes.

Try without the quotes and let me know!

Also,

When testing single variables like string username and int value take a note that WEB API will expect it exactly like that.

This guy,

```
[HttpPost]
public string Test1(int value) { ... }
```

Will look for a post that matches this url signature (im using HTTPIE)...

$ http POST http://yourwebsite.com/api/test1 value=1

Where the "4" is the value of the variable "value" in that Test1 method.

More about HTTPIE here: [Scott Hanselman on installing HTTPIE](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingHTTPIEHTTPForHumansOnWindowsGreatForASPNETWebAPIAndRESTfulJSONServices.aspx)

Hope that helps!

Comment: I found just change the method parameter, adding [FromBody], then it is fine. like: public string Foo([FromBody] string para1). Thanks for your answer anyway~

Answer (score 18):

You need to decorate your string or int parameter with the [FromBody] attribute.

> [HttpPost]
> public string Test([FromBody]string username)
>
> [HttpPost]
> public int Test1([FromBody]int value)

Answer (score 4):

try this:

the website is accept the value by "[FormBody]", so you should be post by "={0}" 
({0} is replaced by your string data)

```
$.ajax({
    url: "api/values",
    data: "='hello world'",
    dataType: "text",
    type: "POST",
    success: function (data) {
        $("#result").val(data);
    },
    fail: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

see also this answer:
[POST a string to Web API controller in ASP.NET 4.5 and VS 2012 RC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662064/post-a-string-to-web-api-controller-in-asp-net-4-5-and-vs-2012-rc)

Comment: That = symbol is a gotcha especially with the latest version of Web API 2 always need to remember if you are sending a JSON string to the Web API 2 controller action and you have the [FromBody] parameter attribute then you need to add the = symbol to the beginning of your JSON e.g. in your client side ajax call you would concatenate the = symbol to the beginning of the data being posted

Answer (score 0):

I searched nearly a day for this because I want my data to be a JSON, so assuming you need to post one value here it is:

INT:

```
$.post('/api/mywebmethod', { "": 10 })
```

STRING

```
$.post('api/mywebmethod', { "": "10" });
```

CONTROLLER

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult MyWebMethod([FromBody]int id)
{
//do work
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using `Route`

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Product")]
public class ProductController:ApiController
{
[Route("Add"),HttpPost]
public string AddProduct(Product productModel)

[Route("Test"),HttpPost]
public string Test(string userName){}
}
```

**call:** localhost:xx//api/product/Add