# ASP.NET MVC 4 - Web API with only one POST method does not get called

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am doing a Web API which can execute arbitrary SQL (passed from user end via Ajax, hence only SELECT of course) against the database, and return the query result in JSON format.

Suppose I have named this controller myQueryController, and defined it as:

```
public class myQueryController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public string Query(string sql)
    {
        string blll = sql;
        return blll;
    }
}
```

And I have my WebApiConfig.cs like:

```
// other routes

// the new route I added, well, in that my predecessor didn't follow the RESTful convention
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "myQuery",
    routeTemplate: "api/myquery/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new
        {
            id = RouteParameter.Optional,
            action = "Query",
            controller = "myQuery",
        }
);

// default rout
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { 
        controller = "URI",
        id = RouteParameter.Optional ,
    }
);
```

And I post to myQuery via Ajax in Firefox:

```
$.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: "/api/myquery/query/",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        success: function (results) {
            console.log(results);
        }
    }
);
```

But I got 404 error:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:5758/api/myquery/query/"
```

And when I composed the POST request in Fiddler, I got the same 404 error.

If I removed the new route definition in WebApiConfig.cs, I still got the same error.

Any help is highly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Firstly, you are miss using `Post`, you should be using `Get` for queries. Secondly, do not ever send SQL from the client to the server like this! Look at using something like OData to allow the client to construct queries without having to expose your database structure to the client

Comment: Totally agree with @TrevorPilley about being a bad idea to pass SQL around like that as you're bypassing security, leaving yourself open to SQL injection and all manner of nasty things.

Comment: Thanks, I am completely aware of what you reminded me, though, it is just out of my control. In my current situation, security concern makes no sense if we cannot deliver the functionality before the deadline, have to handle it in a quick & dirty way.

Comment: @VincentZHANG in that case, no offence but I hope I don't have an account with the service your company offers!

Answer (score 0):

If the POST method expects a basic type value such as string type in my case, then you have to put '[FromBody]' before the argument:

```
[HttpPost]
public string Query([FromBody]string sql)
{
    string myLocal = sql;
    return myLocal;
}
```

And to pass a string to the query method, your Ajax would be like:

```
$.ajax({
    url : "/api/myquery/query",
    data : "=select * from table",
    dataType : "text",
    type : "POST",
    success : function(res){ console.log(res); },
    error : function(req, stat, err){ console.log(stat + ": " + err); }
});
```

I found the solution from this post: [ASP.NET WebAPI throw 404 if method parameter is string or int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13625785/asp-net-webapi-throw-404-if-method-parameter-is-string-or-int), but I found that the single quotation marks around the string 'hello world' are not necessary, which you may find in the 3rd answer.

> data: "='hello world'",